# How to select and sort records with biggest column size by characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table **Customers**

```
ID    NAME LETTER
001   TOM  Lorem Ipsum
002   JEK  Lorem Ipsum
003   MAX  texttexttexttext...(30k letters)
004   JIZ  NULL
005   ZAK  texttexttexttext...(50k letters)
```

The 'Letter' data type in DB is 'text', I have some records that contain 50k+ letters even my microsoft sql client wont load the full size of it :/

Anyways I need to select IDS that have the biggest lenght by symbols at letter column

I tried next one:
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM Customers
ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(Letter);

but looks like my db/sql client dsnt have that function :/
also I tried len(Letter) but argument data type is invalid for len function(

Comment: Why are you using `text`? It's been deprecated for ***16 years***. It's *long* past time you switch to using `MAX` length character types. As you've found out, because you're using said deprecated type you can't use `LEN` against the column. I suggest fixing *that* problem first, as the `MAX` data types do support simple things like the `LEN` function.

Comment: Im not a dev of this thing(

Comment: Then inform your Dev of their poor design choice.

Comment: haha) that is microsoft project btw and this thing cant be changed I just need to select what I need)

Comment: If you work for Microsoft, then you/your team should know better than to use functionality that your own company deprecated 16 years ago. ;)

Comment: ahhaha man I cant do anything with that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the actual number of characters in the text field, cast it to a `varchar`, that should work for most scenarios:

```
select top(100) *
from Customers
order by len(cast(letter as varchar(max))) desc
```

If you want bytes, `text` can be used with `datalength`

```
select top(100) *
from Customers
order by datalength(letter) desc
```

Comment: Yes it does, @Austin . `MAX` datatypes support up to 2GB of data; for a `varchar` that's over 2 **Billion** characters.

Comment: You recall incorrectly, @Austin. A non-`MAX` length character/binary data type supports up to 8,000 bytes, which for a `varchar` (in a non-UTF-8 collation) is 8,000 characters. Again, a `MAX` allows up to 2GB of data.

Comment: @Austin thanks, also its possible to somehow get the lenght in symbols of longest records?